# While inserting nested document in MongoDB, its inserting the nested document with an id. Why is that happening and how to stop that?

Tags: mongodb

I am inserting a nested document in MongoDB but the nested part of the document is getting inserted with an Object ID. Below is my schema -

```
const ticketDetail = mongoose.Schema({
    ticketCount: { type : Number },
    amount: { type : Number },
    pxCount: { type : Number },
    luggageCount: { type : Number },
    cgst: { type : Number },
});
const PaymentModeWiseTDSchema = mongoose.Schema(
        busNumber: { type : String },
        cityId: { type : String },
        cash: ticketDetail,
        prepaid: ticketDetail,
        wallet: ticketDetail,
        pass: ticketDetail,
        mobile_pass: ticketDetail,
        card: ticketDetail,
    {
        collection: 'PaymentModeWiseTD',
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
```

Inserted document looks like this -

```
{
  _id: 62cc2c69e37ebc0015c0ed43,
  busNumber: 'MP09FA9024',
  cityId: '46594857',
  updatedAt: 2022-08-26T12:41:14.806Z,
  cash: {
    _id: 6308bf6abb6710802f39571d,
    amount: 5,
    pxCount: 4,
    ticketCount: 3,
    originalAmount: 5
  },
  mobile_pass: {
    _id: 6308bf6abb6710802f39571b,
    amount: 2,
    pxCount: 1,
    ticketCount: 1,
    originalAmount: 2
  },
  pass: {
    _id: 6308bf6abb6710802f39571a,
    amount: 234567,
    pxCount: 1,
    ticketCount: 1,
    originalAmount: 20
  },
  prepaid: {
    _id: 6308bf6abb6710802f39571c,
    amount: 8,
    pxCount: 1,
    ticketCount: 1,
    originalAmount: 2,
    discountAmount: 2
  }
}
```

I am inserting it without the objected IDs just the values. But it still automatically adds the object ids to the document. How is it happening?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html):

```
By default, Mongoose adds an _id property to your schemas.
```

You may want to look into [Subdocs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html). There also might be a way to reconsider how you're modeling your data. It's hard to understand what you're trying to do without a description of your scenario.